# Check for null value in object in if statement in jquery tmpl

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am quite new to jquery tmpl. I need to check if a certain value is null or not inside if condition. I have the following template:

```
<div class="ui-body">
    {{if !${provider}}}
       <span>Provider is ok</span>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

Whenever I try to bind the following object with the template:

```
{ 
   provider:null
}
```

but in return I get the following error:

> unexpected token {

Comment: In your template code you have closed curly brace thrice instead of twice please correct and check if it's working

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for checking conditional statement ,**no `$` sign or `curly brace` is required**.I did it like the following and it works:

```
{{if provider }}
```

it checks if the condition is truthy or falsy against the variable `provider`